# Handle power loss when processing MySQL query on Java?

Tags: java, mysql, resume

I'm building a Java application that uses a database. I used MySQL for database and JDBC for its connection.

My application will process a lot of data so it will take much time and I'm afraid when the computer loses its power by accident or something else. Is there a way to resume the process, so it won't process from the beginning?

Comment: Remember what has been processed .. this might be a good use of Message Queues.

Comment: As pst said, keep log of amount of data processed. And optimise your Query to process only remaining data, in case of rerun whole processing.  however, you should give a thought about Backup power as well!

Comment: Are you more worried about having to start over, or worried about the DB being in an in-between state?

Comment: MySQL Documentation for data recoery
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/backup-strategy-example.html

Comment: thanks for all reply.
@pst unfortunately I don't know how to remember the process.
@MayurPipaliya Yes, but I just can get log when the query is `insert` I'm be able to know how many row has been inserted, but for `select` I don't know how, so I must rerun the `select` process.

Answer (score 2):

The general steps:

1. Buy and use a UPS (Uninterruptible power supply) that will keep your system running for at least 15 minutes.
2. Write your code so that long-running transactions can be interrupted via a signal
3. Program the UPS software to signal your program when power goes out, so that it can pause the current unit of work and shutdown gracefully
4. Choose transaction sizes carefully to ensure commit/rollback can be completed within the available UPS time (thanks to @Fildor for this one)

Comment: 4. Choose transaction sizes carefully.

Comment: Thanks Mr. @Fildor, it'll be my last choice

Comment: pardon me @Fildor, what do you mean by "pause current work" ? am I be able to pause query processing?

Comment: @Fahmi That was from Jim :) What he means is that in case of a detected powerloss you'll have to stop putting tasks to the "Todo"-list. THat way the DB can finish the last transaction and then go down in a controlled manner. Of course you'll have to redo some of the work, that has not yet been written. But going down uncontrolled and with DB in an inconsistent state would be far worse in any setup.

Comment: oo sorry my bad.. thanks again @Jim . I'll consider your good suggestions.